# Advanced Find giving wrong(?) result

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am using `Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011`.

I have to get all the activities which are of type Appointment, Campaign Activity, E-mail, Opportunity Close, Phone Call, Recurring Appointment or Task. There are some more filters added as per my need. I am using `Advanced Find` for this one. Till this, my advanced find looks like:

[image]

It is returning me results, which are valid.

Now, I want to add another clause to this and shortlist the results which I am getting till now. The clause is: Don't show me the activities (most of which are E-mails) in which sender or recipient contains 'Test'.

For this I have designed following:

[image]

As per me, this should give correct results, but this is returning me no records.

Comment: If you want to downvote, please let me know the reason.

Comment: Wasn't me the downvote. That last filters shouldn't it be an OR for both instead of an AND for each?

Comment: But, that would be like...(either participation type is Sender OR party does not contain 'Test') AND (either participation type is 'ToRecipient' OR party does not contain 'Test'). Won't it be?

Comment: I'm not familiarized with this tool. I think I understand it, and what I mean is the OR covering the two ands like you did on the activity type. Because as it is it seems that you need part type and party with sender and test AND partici type and party with to recipient and test which i think would not evaluate to true since it is the same fields

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that. It gives me all the results including the ones which have sender that contain'Test' and the ones which have ToRecipient that contains 'Test'. This happens because while doing OR, even if one of the criteria is false, it checks the other one and it is true (as we do not have any case in which both sender and recipient contain 'Test'). But, let me try something else based on the idea that you have given me.

Comment: I thought on (participation type equals (sender OR to recipient)) and party does not contain Test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105828/discussion-between-vikram-and-jorge-campos).

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your requirement:

> Don't show me the activities (most of which are E-mails) in which
> sender or recipient contains 'Test'.

It can be rewritten as: Show me all activities where:

- `Sender` contains data
- `Sender` does not contain *test*
- `To Recipient` contains data
- `To Recipient` does not contain *test*

That can be done in the following way (where you go down to the `Sender` Activity Party, back up to Activity and then down to the `To Recipient` Activity Party):
[image: Activity Party filtering, Sender and To Recipient]

This approach requires that the returned Activities have both types of Activity Party (which is probably only true for most Emails), which might not be what you intended.

To keep it simpler, you might be able to do with simply avoiding any Activity Party containing *test*:

[image: Activity Party filtering, all types of Activity Party]

Note that also this approach (as well as your approach) only shows Activities that actually have an Activity Party.

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you have any Emails in the system? Do they have both Sender and Recipient? How does the second query work?

Comment: @Henrik...Sorry, I did not reply you earlier. I tried second query. It shows me all the emails (the ones which has sender as '*Test*' as well as the ones which have To Recipient as 'Test').

Answer (score 0):

just wondering if your activity party conditions should be grouped under "OR".. otherwise, it's "AND" altogether, so you are currently looking for the activities where your activity party is both a sender and a recipient.. In other words, maybe this would work?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried this. This does not filter out any results (it shows me all the activities, even with test as a part of senders and test as part of recipients). This happens because if you read query carefully, it says display record either if sender does not contain 'Test' OR if recipient does not contain 'Test'. So, if sender contains 'Test', but recipient does not contain 'Test', it displays record. Similarly, if recipient contains 'Test', but sender does not contain 'Test', it displays record. Hence, we should use AND condition.

Comment: Point taken.. You need "does not exist" type of join between activities and activity parties, but it is not well-supported by CRM. In theory, this can be achieved using left-outer in fetch-xml(which is not supported by CRM advanced find either): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531006.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 I just tried it quickly by updating solution xml file.. not working yet.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think, it does not give any version for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, which I am using. So, I am not sure whether it is supported in it. Let me try the solution for 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go deeper:

(pardon the ASCII art, don't have a screenshot at hand now: this is how the advanced find window should look)

```
Look for: Activities

Activity Type             Equals           E-Mail;...
(put all the other conditions here)
Activity Parties (Activity)
    Participation Type        Equals        Sender;To Recipient
    Party(User)
        Full Name                 Does Not Contain           test
```

In this PoC I'm assuming all parties are System Users. You cannot mix different kinds of activity parties (such as, an e-mail sent to a contact).

Comment: Thanks for your response. When you write 'Activity Parties (Party)', did you actually mean that or you meant 'Activity Parties (Activity)'? I do not see any option as 'Activity Parties (Party)'.

Comment: @Vikram Too many parties... Activity Parties (Activity) is indeed correct [fixed in the answer text]